# I'm stuck at TWRP recovery menu,whenever I turn on my device.

Tags: rooting, stock-android, twrp

I had a perfectly good root on my Samsung Tab (SM-T111).
However I downloaded and installed "quick reboot" from play store.  I selected boot to recovery (in the app).
Now whenever I try to turn on my device I'm stuck in the Twrp recovery menu.  What to do?

Comment: Just so we're clear, choosing "reboot to system" in TWRP itself also still reboots to TWRP, right?

Comment: Yes. Anything I do I return to TWRP recovery

Comment: You should try uninstalling the app that is causing this issue from TWRP. Do you get any feedback from `adb devices`?

Comment: Could you point out which **quick reboot** app you installed? Should we have a link, we could then tell you how to uninstall said app from TWRP.

Comment: It seems you erased system partition and there is simply no OS to boot to.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman The quick reboot app by "AntaresOne Software".

Comment: @Suncatcher I think so too.I have flashed the stock rom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably flashed TWRP both as recovery and as boot. to fix this just install the latest version of your ROM or flash you ROM's boot.img as boot;

```
fastboot flash boot [boot.img]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the entire internal storage to boot in system OS. I was stuck like this for a while.